# Can etree.XMLParser in recover mode still throw a parse error?

Tags: python, unit-testing, lxml

I have a utility method that parses XML using a parser created as `etree.XMLParser(recover=True)`. I would like to test failure scenarios in a unit test. Except for empty input throwing an `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError`, I can't seem to break the parser.

My question is: is it possible to construct a `StringIO` or `BytesIO` input for this parser such that the parser throws a parse error?

Here's some examples (tested with Python 3.5 and lxml 4.3.3):

```py
from io import BytesIO
from lxml import etree


def parse(xml):
    parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
    elem = etree.parse(BytesIO(xml), parser)
    print(etree.tostring(elem))


parse(b'<broken<')  # prints b'<broken/>'
parse(b'</lf|\jf>')  # prints None
parse('<?xml encoding="ascii"?><foo>æøå</foo>'.encode('utf-8'))  # prints b'<foo/>'
parse(b'')  # Throws lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError
```

Answer (score 3):

If I slap a NULL character at the beginning of any of the bad inputs you show that don't raise an error, I do get an error. For instance:

```
parse(b'\0<broken<')
```

produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    parse(b'\0<broken<')  # prints b'<broken/>'
  File "test.py", line 9, in parse
    elem = etree.parse(BytesIO(xml), parser)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3435, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1857, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1877, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1765, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1127, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 640, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 1
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty, line 1, column 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it because you are using recover=True?

> recover - try hard to parse through broken XML

I changed recover=False and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./foo.py", line 11, in <module>
    parse(b'<broken<')  # prints b'<broken/>'
  File "./foo.py", line 7, in parse
    elem = etree.parse(BytesIO(xml), parser)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3435, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1857, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1877, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1765, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1127, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 640, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 1
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: error parsing attribute name, line 1, column 8
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm using `recover=True` on purpose. I'm basically interested in knowing if I still need to catch `ParseError` in recover mode, and if so, how I can create input that triggers this exception.

Comment: You cannot, unless you hack etree code in lxml. By the time you catch the exception, the execution context is gone. Only thing you can do is to run it twice, once with recover=False with try/except, and if it does exception, run it again with recover. It looks like written in Cython so the task of hacking it is a bit more involved. If you use XML's etree (python one), it's probably easier to modify to do what you want (in python).